# How to correctly release the memory of OpenCvSharp.Mat?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, opencv

Do I have to call the Dispose function? Or use the block using?
And if so, when should I do it?
In DotNet writing I'm not wonted thinking about releasing a memory, so I'm afraid to make a mistake and cause a leak of memory.

Comment: in general, if something implements a `Dispose` method it needs to be disposed of to release resources that it allocated.  There are a very few things like `MemoryStream` that have the method simply as a result of inheritance but there a few of these.  A `Using` / `using` block just does the disposing for you.  This is a bit broad and something you can (and should) research given the nature of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disposing an object has nothing specifically to do with memory. Disposing an object releases its managed and unmanaged resources. An unmanaged resource is basically something that belongs to the OS, e.g. a file handle. A managed resource is basically a .NET object that itself holds managed or unmanaged resources. When you dispose a .NET object, it may dispose another .NET object, that disposes and other .NET object, that releases an unmanaged resource.

There's no specific requirement for you to call `Dispose` on objects that support it because such an object will be finalised by the garbage collector at some point and that will dispose it. It's preferable for you to explicitly release those resources when you know that they are no longer needed though. This means that they are returned to the OS sooner and also that the GC can reclaim the memory that the objects occupy sooner.

If you create an object and know that it is no longer required within the same scope, e.g. within the same method, then you should create it with a `Using` statement so that it will be implicitly disposed at the end of the block. The disposal is guaranteed to occur, even if an exception is thrown and not caught within the `Using` block.  This:

```vb
Using obj As New SomeDisposableType
    '...
End Using
```

is equivalent to this:

```vb
Dim obj As New SomeDisposableType

Try
    '...
Finally
    obj.Dispose()
End Try
```

If the object is still required outside the block it is created in the you cannot use a `Using` statement.  In that case, you should do your best to identify when it is no longer required and call its `Dispose` method explicitly at that point.  At the very least, you should call its `Dispose` method inside the `Dispose` method of the object that created it.  That is an example of releasing a managed resource.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer!
If I understood you correctly, I could create a new instance of Mat inside a function and be sure that GC would call the Dispose function sometime after my function is finished. Right?

Comment: You call `Dispose` when the object will no longer be used, wherever that happens to be.

Comment: And if I forget to do it, will GC call Dispose anyway sometime?

Comment: Yes, the GC finalises everything at some point as a safeguard but you should not rely on that if at all possible. I've only encountered one case where I had to do that in my 14 years of .NET development.